# KONG gateway api testing failing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-403

[image: Sample Image]defined api and path am currently testing KONG gateway api load testing using jmeter

Am getting 403 error.

Please suggest me how can I resolve this issue thanks in advance.

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status Code 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) means **Forbidden** so either your `apikey` parameter is not correct or you're passing it in a wrong way.

Also I have a doubt regarding your URL, if your endpoint is protected with [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) you either need:

1. To add your password to the URL like:

   ```
   ec2user:your_password@ec2-52-70-117-82.....
   ```
2. Or to remove this `ec2user@` from the hostname field and provide it along with the password via [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)